# Admob Iphone Banner ID Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, admob

I'm trying to integrate AdMob in my App all work properly but i get this error 
error: 'MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID' undeclared (first use in this function)

for this line of code

```
  bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
```

in the Admob settings in their i got my publisher code xxxxxxxxxxb6b0e

where to put it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in the head of your .m file:

```
#define MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID @"xxxxxxxxxxb6b0e"
```